# How an attacker could make sure I dont enter in certain website while using ubuntu?

Tags: linux, networking, malware

How an attacker could make sure I dont enter in certain website while using ubuntu?

My Windows 10 machine has been infected by malware that possibly opened a backdoor. I have make a clone of the Windows 10 machine with the purpose of studying the malware but as I am a bit tired I decided to install Ubuntu while the infected windows10 is there to check certain things -my plan is to make a low level format and start from the beginning- but here is what happened some minutes ago..

I entered into ubuntu and started to make some searches into duckduckgo till all of a sudden duckduckgo was inaccessible. I understand my whole computer could be affected and that ubuntu could be tampared aswell however I am asking me how would be possible for a hacker to make sure I am not able to enter into duckduckgo.I was able to enter into google and checked in another computer that duckduckgo was accesible.

So thats the question really. I know a hacker could change the hosts file in windows -though this have never happened to me before- what ways someone that has root access -or not- has to be able to do this?

Comment: I am only asking how an attacker could make sure I would not be able to enter into duckduckgo while I am using ubuntu. That is all. I dont really am able to realize of such a way, if you think that is a stupid question, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

"How an attacker could make sure I dont enter in certain website while using ubuntu?"  Simply put, *it cant*.

You installed Ubuntu.  Even though Windows was infected with a virus, it has no way of affecting Ubuntu.  First off, booting into Ubuntu means Windows did not load and therefore the virus could not run.  In addition to that, it is a Windows virus and Windows cannot read the file systems that Ubuntu uses.

Your inability to connect to DuckDuckGo is most likely an intermittent network problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still have my doubts though.

Comment: @AnonUser4 you can doubt all you want, that doesnt change the facts.

Answer (score 1):

Wide topic to be answered exhaustively, nonetheless:

- First an annotation: if you visited an infecting page **without the needed precautions you may be exposed twice to the same virus** before with windows and after with Linux... there are many pages that are able to act in a different way reading your OS (or better the OS your browser *"communicates"* to the page).
- There is at least one possibility for a malicious code to obtain the same result with only one successful attack: to aim to your **router** and to change the DNS from there. So all the devices that will get the DNS from that router will be affected.

  > Attackers often seek to change the DNS server setting on your router, pointing it at a malicious DNS server. When you try to connect to a website — for example, your bank’s website — the malicious DNS server tells you to go to a phishing site instead. <sup>[[1](http://www.howtogeek.com/227384/how-to-check-your-router-for-malware/)]</sup>

  You can read more on internet about the Router Attacks... starting from this page of [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/227384/how-to-check-your-router-for-malware/).

---

To answer to your first question,  it's enough to change the DNS, the routing or the `/etc/hosts` file under Ubuntu ...